# R ggvis linked_brush is not reactive

Tags: r, ggvis

I have the following code on my Server. R

```
data_agg_plot1<- reactive({
    
    brush1 <- linked_brush(keys = data_agg()$id, "navy" )
    
    data_agg <- data_agg()
    plot1<-data_agg%>%
      ggvis(x = ~dates_all) %>%
      group_by(factor(dates_all.1)) %>%
      layer_points(y =  ~ value, fill =~dates_all.1, shape =~dates_all.1) %>%
      layer_paths(y =  ~ value, stroke = ~dates_all.1 , strokeOpacity := 0.5) %>%
      scale_ordinal("fill", range = c("green", "red", "blue"))%>%
      scale_ordinal("shape", range = c("triangle-up","triangle-down","circle")) %>%
      scale_ordinal("stroke",range=c("green","red","blue")) %>%
      brush1$input() %>%
      hide_legend(c('stroke','fill'))%>%
      add_legend(c('shape','fill'),
                 title = "Symbol", orient = "left",
                 values = c("New hires", "Attrition" , "Net Growth"),
                 properties = legend_props(
                   title = list(fontSize = 16))) %>%
      add_axis("x",properties= axis_props(labels = list(angle=60,align = "left")),
               tick_padding =0,
               title = "") %>%
      add_axis("y", title = "Total Count") %>%
      set_options(width = "auto",height = 400) %>%
      scale_numeric('y',clamp = TRUE)
    
    return(list(plot1,brush1))
  })
```

so this is a reactive function that returns me a list of 2 functions, a plot and my brush object.

the purpose of doing so is so that I can make my keys reactive - this is so that I can make an additional plot based on my user's selection. think of it as the second plot depends on what the first user highlights in the first plot.

this is my following code:

```
  plot1_data<-reactive({
    data_agg_plot1()[[1]]
  })
  plot1_data%>%bind_shiny("plot1")
  
  
  selected_plot1 <- reactive({
    data_agg_plot1()[[2]]
  })
  
  output$test <- renderPrint({
    temp <- selected_plot1()$selected()
    print(temp)
  })
```

however, when I print out the selection, it is all false,

please refer to the image below:

[image]
can anybody explain to me how to overcome this?

I highly suspect I have to re-write my linkedbrush function,

I have tried both solutions from:

[linked_brush in ggvis cannot work in Shiny when data change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28491576/linked-brush-in-ggvis-cannot-work-in-shiny-when-data-change)

but it does not work.

Comment: Hi, Low Yi Xiang, I have the same issue the logical vector which is generated is all FALSE. Were you able to solve this issue. Please let me know if you have a workaround for this. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I was able to solve this issue. instead of using linked brush, I was able to use **handle_brush()**  function. I am able to select a subset of data from a scatter plot and able to get the columns returned.